# Using ACRA with tracepot as backend

Tags: android, acra

I have just finished my first android app as part of a school project ..one of my friends encountered a problem while trying to explore one of the activities in the app ..so i searched for solutions to get the crashes reports whenever they happen to fix the bugs ..i came across ACRA ..and I followed one of SO threads to setup ACRA to my app ..

**RESULT**: when the crashs happens the gmail app get launch in the device and the user (if he want to) he'll send the crash report by email ..Consedering not all users will want to ..i found in a comment in one of the SO threads that some developers use tracepot.
so i have used their link for integration in formUri but exploring my account on tracepot i get nothing ..is there something i am doing wrong (or if there is a better solution than using tracepot a backend , please suggest/explain or link a good tutorial, thanks!)
MyApplication.Java ( **AFTER EDITING**

```
@ReportsCrashes(


 formUri = "https://collector.tracepot.com/79b1***",
         reportType = org.acra.sender.HttpSender.Type.JSON,
    httpMethod = org.acra.sender.HttpSender.Method.PUT,
                mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
        resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text
)
public class MyApplication extends Application {
     @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

  CaocConfig.Builder.create()
            //.errorActivity(CustomErrorActivity.class) //default: null (default error activity)
            .apply();

        // The following line triggers the initialization of ACRA
        ACRA.init(this);
    }
}
```

EDIT :
msg in logcat if i use the http and email:

```
09-17 18:37:33.700 14329-14812/ma.ac.iav.menunaviagtion:acra W/ACRA: ma.ac.iav.menunaviagtion reports will be sent by email (if accepted by user).
09-17 18:37:33.703 14329-14812/ma.ac.iav.menunaviagtion:acra I/ACRA: Sending report /data/user/0/ma.ac.iav.menunaviagtion/app_ACRA-approved/2018-09-17T18:37:33.441+01:00-IS_SILENT.stacktrace
```

if i use only the http :

```
09-17 22:47:00.648 20116-20137/ma.ac.iav.myapplication:acra E/ACRA: Failed to send crash report for /data/user/0/ma.ac.iav.myapplication/app_ACRA-approved/2018-09-17T22:44:52.199+00:00-IS_SILENT.stacktrace
```

IMPLEMENTATION:

```
compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.9.2'
```

LOGCAT FOR F43nd1r

```
09-18 01:39:49.631 18508-18803/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-5
    Process: ma.ac.iav.myapplication, PID: 18508
    java.lang.InternalError: Thread starting during runtime shutdown
        at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:733)
        at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.startLoadFromDisk(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:119)
        at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.<init>(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:112)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.getSharedPreferences(ContextImpl.java:392)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.getSharedPreferences(ContextImpl.java:373)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:167)
        at cat.ereza.customactivityoncrash.CustomActivityOnCrash.getLastCrashTimestamp(CustomActivityOnCrash.java:673)
        at cat.ereza.customactivityoncrash.CustomActivityOnCrash.hasCrashedInTheLastSeconds(CustomActivityOnCrash.java:683)
        at cat.ereza.customactivityoncrash.CustomActivityOnCrash.access$200(CustomActivityOnCrash.java:52)
        at cat.ereza.customactivityoncrash.CustomActivityOnCrash$1.uncaughtException(CustomActivityOnCrash.java:112)
        at org.acra.builder.ReportExecutor.endApplication(ReportExecutor.java:269)
        at org.acra.builder.ReportExecutor.dialogAndEnd(ReportExecutor.java:254)
        at org.acra.builder.ReportExecutor.access$400(ReportExecutor.java:42)
        at org.acra.builder.ReportExecutor$2.run(ReportExecutor.java:217)
```

Comment: What ACRA version are you using?

Comment: @Martin i'm using the 4.9.2 version

Comment: this the only i added to the gradle compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.9.2'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, if the mail config is present, Acra 4 will send via mail and nothing else.
To use both you'd have to configure the `reportSenderFactories`.

---

> 400: Client error

Indicates that tracepot rejected your report. This could have multiple reasons. To find out what the problem is, call `ACRA.DEV_LOGGING = true;` right before `ACRA.init` and post all logcat with the `ACRA` tag.

---

Also note that ACRA `4.9.2` does not support android Oreo and above, it is recommended to upgrade to at least ACRA `4.11`, or just the newest version `5.2.0`.

Comment: I solved the problem by removing the send via mail and the customreportcontent ..now the crash report get sent to tracepot ..but the Ereza/CustomActivityOnCrash doesn' work if ACRA is used ..do you know why? Thanks ..for the versions" i tried 5.2.0 but failed build  ..same for 4.11

Comment: i did found on this website that i should init the customcrash before the ACRA wish i did but no luck? am i doing something wrong? https://www.javatips.net/api/cnBetaReader-master/app/src/main/java/com/ywwxhz/crash/CustomActivityOnCrash.java# Please see my edit post

Comment: I am sorry ..where should i use this and what is the purpose?

Comment: Put it in your acra config. It'll make Ereza/CustomActivityOnCrash (and other crash handlers) work.

Comment: `09-18 01:41:55.555 19302-19357/? E/CustomActivityOnCrash: App has crashed, executing CustomActivityOnCrash's UncaughtExceptionHandler
    java.lang.InternalError: Thread starting during runtime shutdown`

Comment: When the app crashes ..i got what i commented above in logcat ..PS: it's random , it works one time and other times it does not ..thanks for the help

Comment: PS: i have poste the logcat in my edit post ..you'll find it at the bottom of the post ..thanks for the help

Comment: consedering this is a new question ..i opened a new thread  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52377715/app-has-crashed-executing-customactivityoncrashs-uncaughtexceptionhandler ..please see if you can help

Answer (score 2):

You are not sending all required fields to Tracepot.

https://tracepot.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/355272-what-are-the-required-fields-acra-needs-to-send

- ANDROID_VERSION
- APP_VERSION_CODE
- APP_VERSION_NAME
- PACKAGE_NAME
- REPORT_ID
- STACK_TRACE
- USER_APP_START_DATE
- USER_CRASH_DATE

Comment: Thanks for the info Martin ..but unfortunately it didn't wrok ..i have updated the post , you'll see that i used your entries ..the gmail app still get launch and the user if he want to will send the crash report ..but the report isn't sent to tracepot ..in th edited post you'll see the msg related to acra

Comment: Yeah i did ..then nothing happens , do you too use tracepot ? or do you use another backend ?

Comment: Sorry! i trie again without email , and i got in logcat: 09-17 22:45:22.904 19914-19989/ma.ac.iav.myapplication:acra E/ACRA: Failed to send crash report for /data/user/0/ma.ac.iav.myapplication/app_ACRA-approved/2018-09-17T22:44:52.199+00:00-IS_SILENT.stacktrace

Comment: i found in logcat ..ACRA: 400: Client error - request will be discarded

Comment: I solved the problem by removing the send via mail and the customreportcontent ..now the crash report get sent to tracepot ..but the Ereza/CustomActivityOnCrash doesn' work if ACRA is used ..do you know why?  thanks