# App has crashed, executing CustomActivityOnCrash's UncaughtExceptionHandler

Tags: android

I'm facing a weird problem ..i'm trying to use ACRA along with customcrashactivity library ..but whenever the crash occurs (which is done in purpose) ..the crash report get sent but the customcrash activity appears only sometimes ..other times the app get freeze and stop reacting ..what do you think is the problem ..i have searched for a while for the solution but with no luck .. 
 Application.Java

```
@ReportsCrashes(
        formUri = "https://collector.tracepot.com/79****",
        reportType = org.acra.sender.HttpSender.Type.JSON,
        httpMethod = org.acra.sender.HttpSender.Method.PUT,
        alsoReportToAndroidFramework=true,
        mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
        resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text
)
public class MyApplication extends Application {    

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();

            CaocConfig.Builder.create()
                    .apply();

            ACRA.init(this);


        }
```

Manifest

```
 <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"

 <activity android:name=".CustomErrorActivity"
            android:process=":error_activity"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="cat.ereza.customactivityoncrash.ERROR" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

CustomErrorActivity:

```
public class CustomErrorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_error);
    }

    public void restart (View view){
        finishAffinity();
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
    }

}
```

Gradle

```
compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.9.2'
compile 'cat.ereza:customactivityoncrash:2.2.0'
```

THE ERROR:

```
09-18 02:32:26.629 25629-25957/? E/CustomActivityOnCrash: App has crashed, executing CustomActivityOnCrash's UncaughtExceptionHandler
    java.lang.InternalError: Thread starting during runtime shutdown
        at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:733)
        at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.startLoadFromDisk(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:119)
        at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.<init>(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:112)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.getSharedPreferences(ContextImpl.java:392)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.getSharedPreferences(ContextImpl.java:373)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:167)
        at cat.ereza.customactivityoncrash.CustomActivityOnCrash.getLastCrashTimestamp(CustomActivityOnCrash.java:673)
        at cat.ereza.customactivityoncrash.CustomActivityOnCrash.hasCrashedInTheLastSeconds(CustomActivityOnCrash.java:683)
        at cat.ereza.customactivityoncrash.CustomActivityOnCrash.access$200(CustomActivityOnCrash.java:52)
        at cat.ereza.customactivityoncrash.CustomActivityOnCrash$1.uncaughtException(CustomActivityOnCrash.java:112)
        at org.acra.builder.ReportExecutor.endApplication(ReportExecutor.java:269)
        at org.acra.builder.ReportExecutor.dialogAndEnd(ReportExecutor.java:254)
        at org.acra.builder.ReportExecutor.access$400(ReportExecutor.java:42)
        at org.acra.builder.ReportExecutor$2.run(ReportExecutor.java:217)
```

Comment: Have you ever solved it?